# how to duplicate parent values in multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an multidimensional array like this Array.

```
$array = array(
           'parent1' => 'id',
           'parent2' => 'pw',
           'list' => array(
               array(
                   'child1' => 'value1',
                   'chlid2' => 'value2'
               ),
               array(
                   'child1' => 'value3',
                   'chlid2' => 'value4'
               )
           ),
          'parent3' => 'addr'
        );
```

I want to make an array of the top keys and values repeatedly in PHP.
I want Output Like Below.
The order is irrelevant.

```
 $result = array(
        array(
         'parent1' => 'id',
         'parent2' => 'pw',
         'child1' => 'value1',
         'chlid2' => 'value2',
         'parent3' => 'addr'
        ),
         array(
         'parent1' => 'id',
         'parent2' => 'pw',
         'child1' => 'value3',
         'chlid2' => 'value4'
         'parent3' => 'addr'
        )
     );
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far and explain what happens. We're glad to help you sort out specific issues you run into with your existing code, but we're not here to write it for you (which a proper answer to this question would require).

Comment: Hi @gamdong, I have posted my answer which achieves what you are asking. Please let me know if there is anything else I can do to better optimize my answer for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `array_filter()`, `array_merge()`, and a `foreach` loop to accomplish this. We essentially loop through the array and push any items that are not the `list` item to a shallow copy of the list.

### Method #1: If insertion order DOES NOT matter

If order doesn't matter, it's a relatively simple task of pushing each item to the copied original array.

```php
<?php

$array = [
   'parent1' => 'id',
   'parent2' => 'pw',
   'list' => [
       [
           'child1' => 'value1',
           'chlid2' => 'value2'
       ],
       [
           'child1' => 'value3',
           'chlid2' => 'value4'
       ]
   ],
  'parent3' => 'addr'
];

$result = [];

foreach ($array['list'] as &$sub_array) {
    array_push($result, array_merge($sub_array, array_filter($array, function($k) {
        return $k !== 'list';
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY)));
}

echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

This outputs (in JSON format):

```json
[
    {
        "child1": "value1",
        "chlid2": "value2",
        "parent1": "id",
        "parent2": "pw",
        "parent3": "addr"
    },
    {
        "child1": "value3",
        "chlid2": "value4",
        "parent1": "id",
        "parent2": "pw",
        "parent3": "addr"
    }
]
```

### Method #2: If insertion order DOES matter

If order matters, we can walk through the array with a nested `foreach` loop and use `array_merge()` to prepend and append to the `result` array as needed, and use a boolean switch to detect when the `list` item has been passed:

```php
<?php

$array = [
   'parent1' => 'id',
   'parent2' => 'pw',
   'list' => [
       [
           'child1' => 'value1',
           'chlid2' => 'value2'
       ],
       [
           'child1' => 'value3',
           'chlid2' => 'value4'
       ]
   ],
  'parent3' => 'addr'
];

$result = $array['list'];
$list_passed = 0;

foreach ($result as &$item) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === 'list') {
            $list_passed++;
        } else {
            if (!$list_passed) {
                $item = array_merge([$key => $value], $item);
            } else {
                $item = array_merge($item, [$key => $value]);
            }
        }
    }
}

echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

This outputs (in JSON format):

```json
[
    {
        "parent2": "pw",
        "parent1": "id",
        "child1": "value1",
        "chlid2": "value2",
        "parent3": "addr"
    },
    {
        "child1": "value3",
        "chlid2": "value4",
        "parent1": "id",
        "parent2": "pw",
        "parent3": "addr"
    }
]
```

Comment: Please don't answer "gimme code"-type questions that doesn't show any effort at all from the OP's side. Answering these types of questions legitimizes them and basically just reduces this site into a free coding service.